# How could I get the value of a point which including three values?

Tags: function, postgis

I want to get the value of the pointM(including x, y, M), and I don't konw how to get the three value to the returns, the code is:

```
create or replace function point_to_M21(m integer,i integer)
returns float AS
$$
DECLARE
    geo geometry;
    geo1 geometry;
begin
  select testo.geom into geo from testo where lineid=i;
  geo1=st_astext(st_line_interpolate_point(st_geometryN(geo,1),m/st_length(geo)));
  return st_X(geo1);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

> Through the code, I can only get the X value of the point

```
select point_to_m21(56,0);
```

> get the result:

56

> How could I get the reult as this(get the point's three value):

(56,0,56)

> Thanks so much!

Comment: What is relation `testo`? Why do you need a function, rather than just using a normal SQL expression?

Comment: testo is a table's name. Because I need the function which input the line's mile and line's id, return the point's value on the line. And this function I usualy needed, this is the part of rail's line reference content.

Comment: Crossposting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247765/how-could-i-transfer-the-value-of-points-x-and-y. I think, you need the function ST_Line_Locate_Point. Explain better your case and you will get a answer.