# How could I transfer the value of point's X and Y?

Tags: function, postgis

> The function as follows:

```
create or replace function point_to_M(x float,y float, i integer)
    returns float AS
    $$
    DECLARE
        geo geometry;
        geo1 geometry;
    begin
      select testo.geom into geo from testo where lineid=i;
      geo1=st_astext(st_line_interpolate_point(st_geometryN(geo,1),'point(x y)')');
      return st_X(geo1);
    end;
    $$
    language plpgsql;
```

> when I input the SQL:

```
select point_to_M(80,0,0);
```

> The error is:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "point(x y)"
LINE 1: ...ext(st_line_interpolate_point(st_geometryN(geo,1),'point(x y...
```

> So I think the reason maybe is that the paramater didn't transfer into the function, but I am not sure, so does anyone had this problem? Could you tell me the solution? Thanks very much.

Comment: See [ST_MakePoint](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) to make a point from coordinate values. Also, the ST_AsText for the constructor for `geo1` is unnecessary.

Comment: I just want to transfer the value of (x,y) into the function, but it couldn't get the value, I think if I write the way of transfer is not right.

Comment: Your syntax is anyway wrong, but the function ST_line_interpolate_point() does not accept (geometry, geometry) arguments, but (geometry, float). Maybe you need the function ST_Line_Locate_Point instead? See http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Line_Locate_Point.html . Try to explain better want are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert lat long to point

```
create or replace function point_to_M(x float,y float, i integer)
    returns float AS
    $$
    DECLARE
        geo geometry;
        geo1 geometry;
    begin
      select testo.geom into geo from testo where lineid=i;
      geo1=st_astext(st_line_interpolate_point(st_geometryN(geo,1),st_makepoint(x y)));
      return st_X(geo1);
    end;
    $$
    language plpgsql;
```